# Why doesn't Intel compiler vectorize this simple loop (while MSVC does)?

Tags: c++, vectorization, icc

I am investigating vectorization of vector operations. As an example I took common multiplication and addition of 3 vectors. I used Eigen's Vector data types to ensure alignment.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Core"
#include <chrono>
using Eigen::RowVectorXd;
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::nanoseconds;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
//using tbb::tick_count;
int main()
{
    std::cout<<EIGEN_DEFAULT_ALIGN_BYTES<<'\n';
    const int length = 1000;
    RowVectorXd v1 = RowVectorXd::Constant(length, 4.0);
    RowVectorXd v2 = RowVectorXd::Constant(length, 6.0);
    RowVectorXd v3 = RowVectorXd::Constant(length, 7.0);
    RowVectorXd output(length);

    auto  s = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        output(i) = v1(i) + v2(i) * v3(i);
    auto e = high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << output(0) << " Plain loop:" << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(s - e).count()/1000.0<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

MSVC 17 happily unrolls and vectorizes the loop.
Settings:

```
/permissive- /Yu"pch.h" /GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"Release\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /MD /std:c++14 /FC /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\test_loops.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

Disassembly:

```
            output(i) = v1(i) + v2(i) * v3(i);
01121580  movups      xmm1,xmmword ptr [edx+esi*8]  
01121584  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-6Ch]  
01121587  add         esi,8  
0112158A  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [edi-10h]  
0112158E  mulpd       xmm1,xmm0  
01121592  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [eax-20h]  
01121596  addpd       xmm1,xmm0  
0112159A  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [edi]  
0112159D  movups      xmmword ptr [ecx-30h],xmm1  
011215A1  movups      xmm1,xmmword ptr [edx+edi]  
011215A5  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]  
011215A8  mulpd       xmm1,xmm0  
011215AC  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [edx+edi]  
011215B0  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-94h]  
011215B6  addpd       xmm1,xmm0  
011215BA  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [edi+10h]  
011215BE  movups      xmmword ptr [edx+edi],xmm1  
011215C2  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-64h]  
011215C5  movups      xmm1,xmmword ptr [edx+eax]  
011215C9  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-8Ch]  
011215CF  mulpd       xmm1,xmm0  
011215D3  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [eax]  
011215D6  addpd       xmm1,xmm0  
011215DA  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [edi+20h]  
011215DE  add         edi,40h  
011215E1  movups      xmmword ptr [edx+eax],xmm1  
011215E5  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-34h]  
011215E8  movups      xmm1,xmmword ptr [edx+ecx]  
011215EC  mov         edx,dword ptr [v3]  
011215EF  mulpd       xmm1,xmm0  
011215F3  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [eax+10h]  
011215F7  add         eax,40h  
011215FA  addpd       xmm1,xmm0  
011215FE  movups      xmmword ptr [ecx],xmm1  
01121601  add         ecx,40h  
01121604  cmp         esi,3E8h  
0112160A  jl          main+3E0h (01121580h
```

)

However, The Intel Compiler 18 update 4 fails to vectorize. Settings:

```
/permissive- /Yu"pch.h" /GS /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /O2 /Qopt-report:5 /Qopt-report-phase:vec /Fd"Release\vc141.pdb" /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Qipo /Zc:forScope /Gd /MD /std:c++14 /FC /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Qprof-dir "Release\" /Fp"Release\test_loops.pch"
```

Disassembly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
002113D0  xor         edx,edx  
002113D2  xor         eax,eax  
002113D4  nop         dword ptr [eax+eax]  
002113D9  nop         dword ptr [eax]  
        output(i) = v1(i) + v2(i) * v3(i);
002113E0  mov         ecx,dword ptr [v2]  
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
002113E3  inc         edx  
        output(i) = v1(i) + v2(i) * v3(i);
002113E4  mov         esi,dword ptr [v3]  
002113E7  mov         edi,dword ptr [v1]  
002113EA  movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [ecx+eax]  
002113EF  mulsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [esi+eax]  
002113F4  mov         ecx,dword ptr [output]  
002113F7  addsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [edi+eax]  
002113FC  movsd       mmword ptr [ecx+eax],xmm0  
00211401  mov         esi,dword ptr [v2]  
00211404  mov         edi,dword ptr [v3]  
00211407  mov         ecx,dword ptr [v1]  
0021140A  movsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [esi+eax+8]  
00211410  mulsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [edi+eax+8]  
00211416  mov         esi,dword ptr [output]  
00211419  addsd       xmm1,mmword ptr [ecx+eax+8]  
        output(i) = v1(i) + v2(i) * v3(i);
0021141F  movsd       mmword ptr [esi+eax+8],xmm1  
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
00211425  add         eax,10h  
00211428  cmp         edx,1F4h  
0021142E  jb          main+3E0h (02113E0h)
```

I enable detailed vectorization reporting and it shows following.
[image]

So what's wrong? Why is Intel compiler unable to vectorize in contrast to MSVC?

Comment: We're not Intel's customer support.

Comment: You must have a reason to use Intel’s compiler… right? Well, does this experience change anything for you?

Comment: Quality of implementation issue. Not all compilers are equally good at all things and no compiler is *best* at all things.

Comment: I don't know about you but I was taught that a compiler bug is the last thing to suspect. And that the most likely bug sits in the front of the monitor. You say, that is a compiler bug? OK,  but before I assume that and ditch the compiler, I want to make sure that is not my fault.

Comment: A missed optimization is not a compiler bug.